# css анимация прокрука на 180градусов

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

делаю анимацию прокрутка блока на 180градусов

Помогите понять почему блок после завершения встает на 0 градусов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`180deg` - полный 1 оборот, визуально кажется, что возвращается в `0`

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
  
  animation: rotate .5s ease both;
}


@keyframes rotate {
  from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  to { transform: rotate(180deg); }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Что-то уж совсем короткий ответ, ничего не поясняющий)

Comment: @Cheg, напишите развернутый и поясняющий)